# Error in RTI.hh, expected constructor, destructor or type conversion before '&' token

Tags: c++, hla

I have a Modelling environment I am trying to compile using the CERTI Higher Language Architecture Run Time Infrastructure.  In the [process of compiling I have come across a couple of lines of code I don't understand, this also upsets the compiler throws an error.

```
RTI_STD::ostream RTI_EXPORT &
operator<<(RTI_STD::ostream &, RTI::Exception *ex)
```

The error returned is above in the title.  Any help would be appreciated.

---

### Edit 1

More Information:

This is the relevant code I believe:

```
class RTI_EXPORT RTI
{
public:
#include "baseTypes.hh"
#include "RTItypes.hh"

/**
 * RTI (RunTime Infrastructure) Ambassador class.
 * The RTIambassador class is the interface used by an
 * HLA federate to call the RTI. The RTI may call the
 * federate back using the Federate Ambassador class
 * @see FederateAmbassador.
 */
class RTI_EXPORT RTIambassador
{
public:
#include "RTIambServices.hh"
RTIambPrivateData *privateData ;
private:
RTIambPrivateRefs* privateRefs ;
};

/**
 * Federate Ambassador class.
 * The FederateAmbassador is the structure RTI callback class.
 * When the RTI needs to contact the federate it calls one
 * of the FederateAmbassador class methods.
 */
class RTI_EXPORT FederateAmbassador
{
public:
#include "federateAmbServices.hh"
};
};

RTI_STD::ostream RTI_EXPORT &
operator<<(RTI_STD::ostream &os, RTI::Exception *ex);

RTI_STD::ostream RTI_EXPORT &
operator<<(RTI_STD::ostream &os, RTI::Exception const &ex);
```

If you would like the whole file I can provide a link.

My main issue, I think, is I am not sure how the ampersand is being used here?  Any tips?

Comment: The context would be interesting. This is a function declaration (without the trailing semicolon). I *assume* that `RTI_EXPORT` is a DLL symbol import / export macro. But apparently the compiler thinks differently, so it would be nice to see a piece of code that would allow to *reproduce* the error. (This is usually the first step in debugging: Reproduce the error in isolation, or in a context reduced as far as possible.) The error could be in the line before this. Or something could be wrong with the declaration of `RTI_STD::ostream`. Or...

Comment: Thanks for the edit, helpful, +1. The ampersand in `ostream & operator<<()` indicates that the function returns a *reference* to an `ostream` object. (The same reference that gets passed as the first parameter, incidentially.) That is pretty standard syntax. The fact that it's tossing an error for you indicates that something is fishy with `RTI_STD::ostream` or `RTI_EXPORT`. That's about as far as I can take you, not having access to or experience with this particular library. (And seeing those in-class `#include`s, I am not sure I *want* that experience. That's ugly. :-D )

Comment: Thanks for the input @DevSolar.  I will have a look at what I think the class is doing.

Comment: You could start with double-checking that the respective headers where those two suspects are declared *are*, actually, declared where the compiler can see it. Note that the `#include "RTItypes.hh` line is *inside* the `class RTI` declaration, whereas your `operator<<()`'s are not. ;-) (Realized that just now myself.)

Comment: Yes that's what I saw after much time tearing my hair out but moving it inside the paren's just causes a scope error and it now asks for a ; after the &.  All the erros come from the first &, the operator override is fine.

Comment: Nonononono... the `operator<<()` **do** belong outside the class, don't move **them**. Gee, how to put this? An `#include` anywhere else than at the top of the source file is a "code smell": Not a mistake in itself, but an indication of poor design, and a possible source of error. I don't know what those header files are that you are `#include`ing that way, but I'd guess `#include "RTItypes.hh"` should be at the top of the file. All being said and done, you probably shouldn't be fiddling with this RTI stuff at this point, but rather do "vanilla" C++ until you got those things figured out...